# Solution to differential equation $(x^2+y^2)dy = xydx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $(x^2+y^2)dy=xydx$

So I solved this equation as

$log y = \frac{x^2}{2y^2} +C$

and it is given initial conditions is y(1)= 1

and using that we need to find y(e)

however, I'm  getting a quadratic with a logarithm, how do I solve that ?

Comment: Have you heard of Lambert W functions?

Comment: what is a lambert W

Comment: Inverse function for $xe^x$, your solution would be in terms of that... you'd need to look up tables basically

Comment: This came as a jee question, how would I solve this in exam? I don't think they give tables

Comment: Source of the question? I.E the full question

Comment: "The solutio of primitive integral equation "tequation in this questions title". If y(1) =1 and x_o=e then x_o is equal to?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108361/discussion-between-dhanvi-sreenivasan-and-ddd4c4u).

Comment: What I think the question is asking is if $y(x_0) = e$, then $x_0 =?$

Comment: Is it an objective type question? Can you post its options?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan you are correct. The question is not asking for y(e) but x when y(x)=e. See this link : https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/if-x2-y2dyxydx-and-y11-and-yxoe-then-xo-14302

Comment: Kindly clarify your question. Are you asking what $y(e)$ is, or what $y^{-1} (e)$ is?

Comment: oh there was printing error in my book, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with
$$
\left(x^2+y^2\right)\mathrm{d}y=xy\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Converting to polar coordinates
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}r}r&=-\left(\frac1{\sin^3(\theta)}+\frac1{\sin(\theta)}\right)\mathrm{d}\sin(\theta)\\
\log(r)&=\frac12\csc^2(\theta)+\log(\csc(\theta))+\log(\alpha)\\
r&=\alpha e^{\frac12\csc^2(\theta)}\csc(\theta)
\end{align}
$$
Converting back to rectangular coordinates
$$
\begin{align}
y&=\alpha e^{\frac12\frac{x^2+y^2}{y^2}}\\
&=\beta e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}
\end{align}
$$
Solving for $y$:
$$\newcommand{\W}{\operatorname{W}}
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{\beta^2}
&=\frac{x^2}{y^2}e^{\frac{x^2}{y^2}}\\
\W\left(\frac{x^2}{\beta^2}\right)&=\frac{x^2}{y^2}\\
y^2&=\frac{x^2}{\W\left(\frac{x^2}{\beta^2}\right)}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, if $y(1)=1$, we get $\beta=e^{-1/2}$ and therefore,
$$
y=\frac{x}{\W\!\left(ex^2\right)^{1/2}}
$$
where $\W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^2+y^2)dy = xydx$$
$$x(xdy-ydx)=-y^2dy$$
$$x\dfrac {(ydx-xfy)}{y^2}=dy$$
$$\dfrac x yd\dfrac {x}{y}=\dfrac {dy}y$$
$$2\ln y = \dfrac {x^2}{y^2}+C$$
$$y^2=ke^{ \dfrac {x^2}{y^2}}$$
$$Cx^2=\dfrac {x^2}{y^2}e^{ \dfrac {x^2}{y^2}}$$
Inital condition gives us:
$$y(1)=1 \implies C=e$$
Using $W$ Lambert's function:
$$W(ex^2)=\dfrac {x^2}{y^2}$$
$$\boxed {y^2=\dfrac {x^2}{W(ex^2)}}$$